# How to cache ribbon icons in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, ribbon

Whenever I access the admin version of my SharePoint site and want to expand my site actions dropdown menu, it always takes a couple seconds for the icons to finally load and then appear.  Is there way that SharePoint 2010 can cache all of its ribbon icons this way the wait isn't so drastic?

Thanks